# what does Haarclassifier different cascades and stages signify?

Tags: opencv

Does different cascade means different features ? 
what are the different stages ..
For  instance in frontal face detection haar data there are 22 cascades does that means 22 different haar features are used .

Answer (score 1):

No, "number of cascades" means "number of stages" in the whole cascade. 
At any stage in the cascade the classifier rejects the sub-window under inspection.
You should read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viola%E2%80%93Jones_object_detection_framework) for a quick introduction to Viola & Jones algorithm and then get into [this](http://research.microsoft.com/~viola/Pubs/Detect/violaJones_IJCV.pdf) (the original article from the authors).